# IndexOutOfBoundsException while adding to a list in an arraylist

Tags: java, list, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am making a program which has to sort every English word based on the first two letters. Each group of two letters has it's own list which I have to add the words into therefore I have 676 lists in total. I tried making an ArrayList of Lists to do this:

```
public static List<List<String>> englishWordList = new ArrayList<List<String>>(673);
```

Now when I try to add elements to one of the lists I get this an IndexOutOfBoundsException

```
    private static void letterSort(String s){
    //Sorts the words by the first two letters and places in the appropriate list.
    String letterGet = s.substring(0,2);
    for(int i = 0; i < 676; i++){
        if(letterGet.equals(letterCombos[i])){
            Debug(s);
            Debug(letterGet);
            try{
                englishWordList.get(i).add(s); \\IndexOutOfBoundsException here
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help with fixing this would be very appreciated, also if any more information is needed I will be more than happy to add it.

Comment: Might be another problem, but you have declared a list with 673 objects but you are iterating up to 676, so you are trying to access 3 objects that dont exist. Instead of iterating up to 676 I would change to *englishWordList.size()*

Answer (score 0):

You only initialized the `englishWordList`, but you didn't add anything to it. Therefore `englishWordList` is empty and any `get(int)` call will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You can fill it with empty `List`s the following way (also note that you set initial capacity to 673 instead of 676):

```
public static List<List<String>> englishWordList = new ArrayList<List<String>>(676);
static {
    for (int i = 0; i < 676; i++) {
        englishWordList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    }
}
```